# Make flask API private

Tags: python, authentication, flask, oauth-2.0

I have a Flask API which is supposed to be consumed by frontend. Currently it is public. I can invoke it using postman also.

I want to make it private so that only the frontend can consume it and it can't be invoked from any other source.

Went through a few articles/posts suggesting to store credentials and authenticate using the database. I do not want to store it in database or anywhere else. I want to do it in the code itself.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a CORS policy, which allows only the frontend URL to send requests to your server.

> Cross-origin resource sharing is a mechanism that allows restricted resources on a web page to be accessed from another domain outside the domain from which the first resource was served.

In Flask, you can do this by using `flask-cors`: https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Install using `pip install -U flask-cors`.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)

# Replace with your frontend URL
CORS(app, origins=[“http://localhost:8000”, “https://example.com”])

@app.route("/")
def helloWorld():
  return "Hello, cross-origin-world!"
```